# ¿Por qué este script solamente carga NaN en las columnas Signal y Position?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, jupyter

En mi ruta de autoaprendizaje, actualmente estoy estudiando diferentes maneras de implementar estrategias.  La que muestro a continuación debería cargar valores en las columnas **Signal** y **Position**. No lo hace. ¿Cual puede ser la causa?.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import numpy as np

# Importación de datos
start = "2000-1-4"
data = pdr.get_data_yahoo("AAPL", start)

# Estrategia
data['Signal'] = data['Adj Close'].rolling(5).mean() - data['Adj Close'].rolling(20).mean()
data['Position'] = (data['Signal'].apply(np.sign) + 1)/2   # np.sign devuelve una indicación por elementos del signo de un número, devuelve 1 o -1.
data[:5]
```

[image: Salida del sscript]

Comment: Tenes un `rolling(20).mean()`  esto hace una ventana de 20 valores, quiere decir que los primeros 19 valores van a ser `NaN` y un `NaN` en casi cualquier calculo produce `NaN`

Comment: Efectivamente, me faltó  data.dropna(inplace=True)